# Ruby/Cucumber Error: Step definitions must always have a proc or symbol

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

My automation test suite for an application is written using Ruby/Cucumber. When I try to run the tests using the `cucumber` command, and I receive the following error: `Step definitions must always have a proc or symbol`. I can't find any references to this error online except for [the source code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/master/lib/cucumber/glue/step_definition.rb) itself.

Full stack trace:

```
Step definitions must always have a proc or symbol (Cucumber::Glue::StepDefinition::MissingProc)
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/step_definition.rb:29:in `new'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:83:in `register_rb_step_definition'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/dsl.rb:31:in `register_rb_step_definition'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/dsl.rb:133:in `register_rb_step_definition'
C:/Users/westoa1/dev/eclipse-workspace/rms-quality-manager/cucumber/features/step_definitions/data_steps.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:144:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:85:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `each'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `load_files!' C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:272:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:68:in `run!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through my step definition files and found an incomplete step definition with no block:

```
Given 'There is a user'
```

The block was removed while resolving merge conflicts, and completing the step definition solved the error:

```
Given 'There is a user' do 
    (do stuff)
end
```